# ng-if problems when updated value from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, meteor

I'm using AngularJS with Meteor and I'm getting troubles with the Authentication, I'm using accounts-password package in order to use the accounts package methods but implementing my own UI. 
As for now I have this on my ng.html (view) file:

```
<div ng-if="$auth.currentUser">I am visible only for logged in users!

    <br>
    {{ $auth.currentUser.emails }}


    <form>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Logout" ng-click = "logout();">
    </form>

</div>

<div ng-if="!$auth.currentUser">

        <input type="email" name="loginEmail" ng-model = "loginEmail">
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" ng-model = "loginPassword">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Login" ng-click = "login(loginEmail,loginPassword);" >

</div>
```

So if there is a user logged, in the value of $auth.currentUser is not null and the first div should be visible. 
The main problems is that I call $parent.login(...) to do the authentication using the controller, I have this on my Controller:

```
$scope.login = function(loginEmail, loginPassword) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(loginEmail, loginPassword);
            //location.reload();
            //$route.reload();

}
```

And after the login function ends, the $auth.currentUser variable is not null, that's okay and now we should see the other div, but, the ng-if doesn't check again the value of $auth.currentUser until something happens, something like me pressing the button two times or using some of my web page functions for example changing some style or attribute of some div when going over.

So my question is, is there a way to make ng-if check the value again after some method has ended (since this happens as well in Register and Logout methods) or a variable has been updated?

Thanks for your time & answers :)

Comment: I haven't worked with Meteor but for angular is you would bind the ng-if to a property on the $scope it should work when the property changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callback like this,

```
        Meteor. loginWithPassword(loginEmail, loginPassword, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                // TODO: Log error
            } else {
                Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function () {
                    $state.go('your_state_name');   //something like $state.go('home'); 
                });
            }               

            $scope.$apply(function () {
                //you can set any other $scope variables using $scope.$apply
                $scope.isAuthenticating = false;    
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Kishor! I've just implemented and seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JaviAlcañiz Good to know that it worked. If it solves your problem, please accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `loginWithPassword` method can take a third parameter; a callback function. LoginWithPassword is a async method so when the server gives us back answer (and the callback is fired) we need to notify Angularjs that something has happend. Call $scope.$apply() within the callback function.